# how to check how much of a video stream has been seen by user with php

Tags: php, html, video, stream

I'm working on a project which shows video advertisement to user and after 60 second users can see a link. 
My boss wants to be sure users watch all of 60 second. Now I want to know is there any way to check how much of a video stream has been seen by php ? 
To present video as stream I've used this code :

http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

```
class VideoStream
{
    private $path = "";
    private $stream = "";
    private $buffer = 102400;
    private $start  = -1;
    private $end    = -1;
    private $size   = 0;

    function __construct($filePath) 
    {
        $this->path = $filePath;
    }

    /**
     * Open stream
     */
    private function open()
    {
        if (!($this->stream = fopen($this->path, 'rb'))) {
            die('Could not open stream for reading');
        }

    }

    /**
     * Set proper header to serve the video content
     */
    private function setHeader()
    {
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
        header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
        header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
        $this->start = 0;
        $this->size  = filesize($this->path);
        $this->end   = $this->size - 1;
        header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

            $c_start = $this->start;
            $c_end = $this->end;

            list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            if ($range == '-') {
                $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
            }else{
                $range = explode('-', $range);
                $c_start = $range[0];

                $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
            }
            $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
            if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= $this->size) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            $this->start = $c_start;
            $this->end = $c_end;
            $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
            fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header("Content-Length: ".$length);
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this->size);
        }
        else
        {
            header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
        }  

    }

    /**
     * close curretly opened stream
     */
    private function end()
    {
        fclose($this->stream);
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * perform the streaming of calculated range
     */
    private function stream()
    {
        $i = $this->start;
        set_time_limit(0);
        while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
            if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
                $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
            }
            $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
            echo $data;
            flush();
            $i += $bytesToRead;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start streaming video content
     */
    function start()
    {
        $this->open();
        $this->setHeader();
        $this->stream();
        $this->end();
    }
}

$stream = new VideoStream($filePath);
$stream->start();
```

thanks.

Comment: I don't see any attempts in the code above to try to make this happen. All I see is that you linked us code from a tutorial. Where are your efforts?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy,  Actually I attempted base on my experience but it wasn't successful, now I tried to ask weather anybody did this before or not .

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done at client side in java script. You will need to start timer when video starts to playing. Check the Video player API you will need to find event API to execute code on event when video starts. 
For the Advertisement, You will need to overlap your ad container on video screen with the help of css. 
Then execute that code in the function

```
 setTimeout(function(){ 
 //Show your ad container here  
 }, 60000);
 //60,000 is equal to 60 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks , I've check FFMpeg but they don't have any method or class or library to solve my problem.

Comment: You can get frames of first 1 minute then add you video frames in between. it is just like cutting the burger bread in to two parts and put your stuff in to.

Comment: I think you got misunderstood, I have a video with 1 minute duration. I want to show this video to user and become sure that user watched all of 60 seconds. After that i want to show a link to user. 
I just want to check how many seconds user watched the video with php not with javascript or jquery because there are some tricks to cheat javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The servers job was done as soon at the video was downloaded. This must be done client side. You need a piece of javascript that will display the link once the video is played.

Comment: How to check if video played for 60 seconds ? It's necessary for me that users first watch 60 seconds of video then I show the link to them.

Comment: How would depend on your player (html5, flash, etc).

Comment: Can you suggest me a specific player which could be helpful for my problem ?