# Check how much of video is seen by an user in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net

We are developing LMS application using ASP.Net 4.5. The course lectures are captured and made available in Vimeo and same is linked against each course inside tinymce content. When a student clicks on the course content this video gets displayed in our application. The requirement is that we need to track how many times a video is seen by a student and how long the student seen the vide. Is there a possibility to track this. 
I have seen a similar question title in PHP ([how to check how much of a video stream has been seen by user with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148952/how-to-check-how-much-of-a-video-stream-has-been-seen-by-user-with-php)), but I think our requirement is different. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry I dont have any idea how to do this. I'm not looking for a complete code, if someone can give a logic or guide me how to do. I will try and get back. Thanks

Comment: Wonder why there is no answers for this question from this brilliant group

Comment: Because SO is not a code writing service. You have to put in effort, show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Then people might answer.

Comment: Sorry to hear such reply, I had mentioned earlier I dont expect a code at least some clue to try. Any way thanks for atleast replying.

Comment: Sorry to quote, I always admire this group and helped me lot.But the recent comment by VDWWD was like "Some one drowning asks for help do we expect him to try swiming then will see whether we can help."

Comment: To stay in your vocabulary. SO is not a swimming school but rather gives advice on your technique if you want to improve your 50m lap times.

Comment: Sorry  VDWWD if my comments hurts you. I dont like to continue on this topic any more, since other admirable members also check these comments.