# secure way to count video plays

Tags: javascript, php

I've been trying to think of ways to check the validity of plays on any given video that has been served to a user. I don't want to be updating the counter every time a user hits the play button as this could be easily abused. Not only that, the user could always visit the **Ajax** request page which updates the plays directly and then just click refresh until their hearts content.

For an issue I'd assume to be fairly popular, I can't seem to find anything based on the security of it.

One idea I thought might be good would be to check would be to see how much of the content has been streamed when serving the file via **PHP** - but according to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30152758/5859909) answer, that is impossible.

So, how should I approach this problem? Do I bite the bullet and just *hope* that users don't abuse the system (which they definitely will) or is there any solution to this problem?

Cheers.

**EDIT:** Here's an example of something I'd be looking for...

```php
$file = new File($path);
$read = $file->read();
while($read->reading()){
    // if 30 seconds has elapsed
    if($read->elapsed() > 30000){
        // query database
    }
}
```

Comment: in JavaScript, you could add an event handler to the `ended` event - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event - then make an AJAX request to the server to update the playback counter

Comment: @blurfus I _could_... but if the video is 3 hours long it's never going to get any plays...

Comment: Well, you didn't specify that as a requirement in your original question, did you?  - Now, what do you want to count? how many times the video starts playing or just how many times it is served to a user (even if the user never hits the play button) ?

Comment: Have a look at the media events to see if they might be close to what you are seeking: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: There is no way. Whatever method you use requires communicating with the server, and that can *always* be spoofed.

Comment: Maybe recaptcha v3 can help you. You could send an ajax request to the server ~10 seconds after the video starts playing and recaptcha will tell you if it's genuine